# Pixi.js on cordova lag/freeze

Tags: android, cordova, galaxy-tab, pixi.js

I have a lag/freeze on **galaxy tab 3** just for render a picture of 30px/30px (move right x += 1).

I would like to take informations. I have a smartphone lg g3.

On the lg g3 no lag/freeze.

Comment: try decreasing the resolution by making the canvas smaller.  Then use a css width:100% to expand it to fit the screen.

Comment: Thank, the problem is the webview. This default webview is bad in canvas. I take the chromium view with Crosswalk.